# Create a patch using TortoiseSVN

Tags: core, svn, patch

I use TortoiseSVN for managing a couple of plugins I have on the WP repo. Now, I'd like to try my hand at contributing to core with a little patch. I've followed the instructions that can be found here:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/tutorials/working-with-patches/

My patch contains a header with the following info:

```
Index: class-wp-embed.php
===================================================================
--- class-wp-embed.php  (revision 34819)
+++ class-wp-embed.php  (working copy)
```

Apparently, someone told me that this patch cannot be applied correctly because the header doesn't contain the file's full path. The correct header should be:

```
Index: src/wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php
===================================================================
--- src/wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php  (revision 34819)
+++ src/wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php  (working copy)
```

My question is, how can I get TortoiseSVN to add full paths to patch headers automatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I wasn't creating the patch correctly. You have to use the "Create patch..." option in TortoiseSVN on the root folder, not the patched file itself.